# How do I change HTML/CSS header image depending on page width?

Tags: html, css

In my website, I'd like to design a header image in Photoshop. It will be responsive via `max-width:100%` However, at mobile screen width it should change to a different image, something more suited for that size screen. How is that done in HTML or CSS?

Comment: You could use `srcset` - this will load the largest image based on the original screen size, if you resize upwards, it will load the larger images, although if you then resized downwards it will keep the larger image (as I think it is just trying to minimise the download of smaller screen devices): https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

Answer (score 2):

instead of `img` tag use background image for your header and change its src in media query

like

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
    .header{
        background-image: url('img/myimg.jpg');
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    .header{
        background-image: url('img/myimg2.jpg');
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
       .header{
            background-image: url('img/myimg3.jpg');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Problem as I see is that when I make an image responsive with `max-width:100%` it automatically maintains aspect ratio.  How do I get the container div to resize with page width, say `.container { width:1000px; max-width: 100%}` and match the aspect ratio of the background img.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Media Query` you can do something like this or you can change the width to one that fit your needs:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .className {
    //style goes here;
  }
}
```

Check this [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) it will help you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using core CSS and HTML then use Background Image for your header and fix the background size.

```
.header{
        background-image: url('img/myimg.jpg');
        background-size:100% 100%;
    }
```

This will adjust the background view according to display size.

Instead you can use bootstrap classes for best responsive look.

Using Bootstrap Classes:
For small screens:

```
<img id="logo" class="img-responsive hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm visible-xs" src="Images/small-header.png" />
```

For Large screens:

```
<img id="logo" class="img-responsive hidden-xs" src="Images/large-header.png" />
```

You can use images with different dimensions for different size of screens.

```
xs = Extra small,
sm = small,
lg = large,
md = medium,
```

Refer bootstrap for better knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

you can find your answer here http://anzblog.com/2017/05/15/change-htmlcss-header-image-depending-page-width/